# How can we make exceptions to a (Character Class) in ORACLE regex?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to pull all Customer Names from Oracle DB that containing non-standard formats, or invalid characters sequences, ex: (spaces and punctuation repetitions). For that ***general*** purpose I'm using REGEXP_LIKE(Customer_Name, '[[:space:][:punct:]]{2,}') expression.

But I need to allow some exceptions to that ***general*** rule, where some space and punctuation repetitions are acceptable. Attempted to insert them after the "NOT" operator (see my code please).

I'm using the code below:

```
WITH T (id, col) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'GEORGE AND SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'GEORGE P. SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'GEORGE P . SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'GEORGE - P. SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'GEORGE - P . SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'GEORGE- P. SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'GEORGE P, SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'GEORGE P , SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'GEORGE - AUTO . SON'FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'GEORGE P. & SON' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'GEORGE P.&SON' FROM DUAL)

SELECT *
FROM T

WHERE    
        REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[[:space:][:punct:]]{2,}') AND
                    --Exclusions:
                    NOT (REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[[:upper:]]+\. \w') OR   
                         REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[[:upper:]]+ \& \w') OR   
                         REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[[:upper:]]+\, \w') OR
                         INSTR(col, ' - ') > 0                       
                        )            

ORDER BY id
;
```

My problem is that This regex is only bringing the Id's (3, 8, 10 and 11), but should also bring (5, 6 and 9), as explained below:

5 - 'GEORGE - P . SON' : has the exception ' - ' but ' . ' is not valid (spc and punct. repetitions)

6 - 'GEORGE- P. SON' : has the exception 'P. ' but '- ' is not valid (spc and punct. repetitions)

9 - 'GEORGE - AUTO . SON' : has the exception ' - ' but ' . ' is not valid (spc and punct. repetitions)

I need to know please, How can I make exceptions to my ***general*** Regex '[[:space:][:punct:]]{2,}' character class.
In my code when both the general 'rule' and the 'exception' exists in same string this regex doesn't work as expected, as in the cases of Id's (5, 6 and 9).

I really appreciate some help, please.

Comment: I told you yesterday it is not possible, do not repost the same question every day please.

Comment: Yes Wiktor, and I thank you for your Answer. But somebody can have a solution that we both can't see, at least for now...

Comment: There might be another solution, but your requirement is related to regex only, you want to restrict a general pattern. This requires a lookaround, that Oracle regex engine does not support. So, you might probably use a couple of regexps here, but certainly not a single regex solution. I do not see the one-regex solution because there is none... unless Oracle SQL will switch to some other regex engine, as is the case with MySQL that now uses ICU regex beginning with v.8.

Comment: If anyone (I know) knows how to use regular expressions, then it is @Wiktor. If he says *not possible*, then - in my opinion - I believe that it actually *might be* possible, but is not *probable* at all.

Comment: Yes, some workaround might actually exist here, I will try my hand.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could reverse the logic.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor. Can you please show me the way with a possible solution, with an example (code)?